# Trying to update packages using TexLive utility, "unable to find valid update server"

Tags: mactex, update, tex-live-utility

I'm trying to update my packages on a Mac using TexLive Utility. I get an error message: ``**Unable to find a valid update server.** Either a network problem exists or the TeX Live version on the server does not match.  If this problem persists on further attempts, you may need to try a different repository.''

The repository address is http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet.

I tried using a different one (https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/) and I get this message:  ``**Repository has a different TeX Live version.** The repository at https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/ has TeX Live 2021, but you have TeX Live 2020 installed.  You need to switch repositories in order to continue.''

I am using TexLive Utility v. 1.49 (2021).

Comment: That explains it. You have TeX Live 2020 installed. That is frozen and cannot be updated anymore. You will need to install MacTeX 2021 (remember to update it afterwards).

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I still haven't released a version that knows about the 2020 legacy mirror. The [latest beta](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases/download/1.50b1/TeX.Live.Utility.app-1.50b1.zip) will let you update TL 2020 to its final state, but as @daleif says, you need to install MacTeX 2021 or TL 2021 to get current packages.

Comment: I see. So there is no way to use TexLive Utility 2021 without downloading the whole MacTex 2021 distribution?